# How do you solve the equation to where the function $f(x)=1+\sqrt{x}$ and it's inverse $g(x)=(x-1)^2$ intersect?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, factoring

The problem stated in the title comes from an entry-level university/upper secondary school textbook.

My initial attempt to solve it was to expand $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$, from there $x^2-2x+1=1+\sqrt{x}$ and I can subtract 1 from each side. From there I square both sides which gives me $x=(x^2-2x)^2$. If expand the right hand side I get $(x^2-2x)^2=x^4-4x^3+4x^2$. Then I go back and subtract x from both sides and I get $x^4-4x^3+4x^2-x=0$. From this point on however, I have trouble finding a way to continue. I can see how I can divide the terms with x but I don't know if that would help. Since there are the terms $4x^3$ and $-x$ I also can't express $x^4$ and $4x^2$ as $t^2$ and $t$ and solve it using the quadratic formula. The goal is to find the exact point at which these functions intersect. Possibly there is some easier solution than solving it this way so I would be happy to hear any advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that $0$ and $1$ are solution, then with Horner you get quadratic ...

Comment: The equation after squaring has solution $1$. Using this, you can reduce the degree to $2$ and apply the formula for quadratics. Note that you must check whether the solutions satisfy the original equation since squaring usually produes extra solutions.

Comment: I don't think [ordinary-differential-equations], [analysis], and [inverse-function] should be included. Consider removing them.

Comment: @Aqua Or simply with polynomial division.

Comment: Note that inverse of $f(x)$ is, $\quad g(x)=(x-1)^2\quad$ **for $x\ge1$** .

Answer (score 1):

Note that, a strictly increasing function, always intersects its inverse on $y=x$ line. Hence it is enough to find intersection points of $f(x)=1+\sqrt x$ and the line $y=x$,

$$1+\sqrt x=x\Rightarrow (\sqrt x)^2-\sqrt x-1=0$$
$$\sqrt x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$
Since $\sqrt x\ge0$ , only  $\sqrt x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ is acceptable. Hence  $x=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^2=\frac{3+\sqrt5}2$
and intersection point is $\large(\frac{3+\sqrt5}2,\frac{3+\sqrt5}2)$.

Comment: What about $x=0$?

Comment: @Servaes $x=0$ is not in the domain of $f^{-1}(x)$ since $D_g=R_f=[1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that $x \ge 0$ and $x^2 - 2x \ge 0$, because only then do "$\sqrt{x}$" and "$x^2 - 2x = \sqrt{x}$" make sense.

$x^4 - 4x^3 + 4x^2 - x = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow x \cdot (x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x - 1) = 0$

$ \Leftrightarrow x \cdot [(x^3 - 1) - 4x(x - 1)] = 0 $

$\Leftrightarrow x \cdot [(x - 1)(x^2 + x+1) - 4x(x - 1)] = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow x \cdot (x - 1) \cdot (x^2 - 3x + 1) = 0$

Solve the equation, and make sure that the roots satisfy both specified conditions. The other roots are extraneous.